# Is there a way of passing state information from react hooks into nested functions in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, web3js

This is my first solo react project so apologies if I've missed anything glaring. I am trying to find a way to get the {account} and {value} into handlePledge. Obviously you can't use them directly in nested functions. I have tried different things such as passing {account} and {value} as arguments (ie handlePledge({account}, {value})) but no luck.

```
function App() {
  const [account, setAccount] = useState();
  const [button, setButton] = useState('Enable Ethereum');
  const [value, setValue] = useState(1);


  const handlePledge = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const gas = await SixtySixDays.methods.createNewPledge().estimateGas();
    const result = await SixtySixDays.methods.createNewPledge().send({
      from: #account-goes-here,
      gas,
      value: #value-goes-here
    })
    console.log(result);
  }
```

Thank you, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Obviously you can't use them directly in nested functions" ... why not?

Comment: I'm basing this on the hooks rules in the documentation. I realised this after trying it and it not working

Comment: I don't see any problem with just using them as variables in  your `handlePledge` function.  What the issue?

Comment: Well you have to call the hook itself (i.e., `useState`) at the top level in the component, but you can use the state variable (or the set function) anywhere in the function, just normal closure

Comment: Thank you for your help guys, I misunderstood what the docs were saying

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the values directly like this:

```
 const result = await SixtySixDays.methods.createNewPledge().send({
   from: account,
   gas,
   value: value
}
```

"Obviously you can't use them directly in nested functions." - You can and you should

Comment: Thank you Pedro, I misread and misunderstood the docs

Answer (score 1):

You can and should use the any state variables directly.

```
    const result = await SixtySixDays.methods.createNewPledge().send({
      from: account,
      gas,
      value: value
    })
```

The above should work.

Comment: Thank you curious_guy, I misread and misunderstood the docs

Comment: Haha, that happens to the best of us!

Answer (score 0):

As @Nick implies, you in fact *can* use those variables in an enclosed scope.  They are perfectly accessible from functions you declare within their shared scope.

Perhaps your issue is how the rendering is being updated?  If I've not answered your issue, please kindly show the exact error you're getting.

Comment: I have updated to the suggested but it's still not working. The error I'm getting is suggesting that when the form is submitted value is not being passed into send. That is that the value being read is 0, which I can't understand why.